# How to clear placeholder in angular on focus

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How can I clean the value of variable on selecting the input box in angular 2 and angular material.

`<div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." [value]="searchValue" [(ngModel)]="variable" >
</div>`

`export class App {
  }
}`

Comment: instead of having a static text make use of a variable and check the focus by using forms and then empty the variable

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the following CSS:

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color:transparent;
}

input:focus:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color:transparent; 
}

input:focus::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color:transparent; 
}

input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color:transparent;
}
```

See the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/sEczl4arTSNn2tMP6yI4?p=preview).